# Finding next palindrome

Tags: c++, recursion, palindrome

**I am trying to solve a problem related to palindrome which is:**

"For each K, output the smallest palindrome larger than K." (Where K is an integer taken as user input)

I have used the recursive approach but it just throws an error stating SEGMENTATION FAULT....

My approach...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int pal(int x){
    int rev=0;
    while(x!=0){
        int rem=0;
        rem=x%10;
        rev=rev*10 + rem;
        x=x/10;
    } 
    if(rev==x)
        return x;
    else
        pal(x+1);
}

int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int N;
        cin>>N;
        
        cout<<pal(N+1)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please guide me where am I doing wrong.

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior by way of reaching a closing brace of a non-`void` function without encountering a `return` statement. I expect the compiler has issued a warning, something like "not all control paths return a value".

Comment: No it just displays SIGTSTP..

Comment: That's [one possible manifestation](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
else {
pal(x+1);
}
```

write `return pal(x+1);`

Your current pal function does not return any value if the first x+1 is not a palindrome. Based on what @igorTandentik has written in the comments, this should fix the problem.

---

EDIT 1:

Your code has a serious flaw. You're making x zero in your while loop and then comparing it with reverse, which will never be true. Now you are calling pal with x+1 which is equivalent to pal(1). You repeat same mistake in recursive call. Hence you enter an infinite loop.
Make a copy of x in your function then use that copy to reverse the x. use x to compare with reverse or forward it to next call.

Comment: Try testing the fixed program. Does it work if you give it a test case of 1000000002?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. For the given number it worked fine for me, the result was 1000110001. I don't think recursion stack will always overflow even for bigger numbers because we are not recursing from 0 onwards but from large number onwards. so stack might not always overflow. But if you are hinting towards use of unsigned long datatype you might be right but OP has not provided any constraints in question so I'm assuming that his solution might not exceed this limit. Also, the code has problems so I'm editing my answer! Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You are right, the stack should be big enough to handle 32 bit integers.

Comment: @Breakpoint whatever you suggested in "Edit-1" worked ..I was stupid to directly using 'x' in while loop ..Thanks